# Flask: pass message to html without reloading

Tags: flask

```
@app.route('/search_artist')
def search_artist(limit=20):
    token_info = sp_oauth.get_access_token()
    access_token = token_info['access_token']
    print(access_token)
    sp = Spotify(auth=access_token)
    search_artist = request.args.get('search_artist')
    print(search_artist)
    src = request.remote_addr
    print(src)
    results = sp.search(q=f'artist:{search_artist}', type='artist', limit=limit)
    if 'artists' in results:
        if results['artists']['items']:
            artist = results['artists']['items'][0]
            top_tracks = sp.artist_top_tracks(artist['id'])
            songs = []
            for track in top_tracks['tracks'][:20]:
                song = {
                    'name': track['name'],
                    'artist': track['artists'][0]['name'],
                    'uri': track['uri'],
                    'song_source' : track['artists'][0]['external_urls']["spotify"],
                    'artists_id' : track['artists'][0]['id']
                }
                songs.append(song)
            return render_template('results.html', songs=songs, user_src=src)
        else:
            print(f"No results found for '{search_tracks}'")
    else:
        print(f"Error in the search results for '{search_tracks}'")


@app.route('/play/<track_uri>')
def play(track_uri):
    sp = Spotify(auth_manager=sp_oauth)
    print(track_uri)
    devices = sp.devices()
    print(devices)
    device_id = sp.devices()['devices'][0]['id']  # Get the user's active device
    print("device_id: "+str(device_id))
    track_name = request.args.get("page")
    print(track_name)
    src = request.remote_addr
    print(src)
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT count FROM limit_queue_tracks WHERE local_ip=%s",(str(src),))
    get_limit_data = cursor.fetchone()
    if get_limit_data:
        count = get_limit_data[0]
        if count<5:
            count = count + 1
            cursor.execute("UPDATE limit_queue_tracks SET count=%s WHERE local_ip=%s", (count, str(src)))
            db.commit()
            cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM queue WHERE track_uid = %s",(track_uri,))
            track_id = cursor.fetchone()
            if track_id:
                print("Already track present in queue list")
            else:
                cursor.execute("INSERT INTO queue (user,track_name,track_uid) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", ("User1", track_name, track_uri))
                db.commit()
                cursor.close()
            sp.start_playback(device_id=device_id, uris=[track_uri])
            return render_template('playing.html', track_playing="Playing "+str(track_name)+"..")
        else:
            # flash('Looks like you have changed your name!')
            return render_template('results.html', limit=count, user_src=src)
```

When I click a button in html @app.route('/play/<track_uri>') this route will work. Before that there will be lot of datas stored in results.html by /search_artist. When my count is greater than 5 I have done return render_template('results.html', limit=count, user_src=src) but my datas disappeared. I need to keep the datas and pass message. Is there any solution